# How to use systemd-resolve instead of connman as DNS proxy?

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved, connman

Every time that I start my computer, my DNS does not work. In `/etc/resolv.conf` I see:

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I see that `/etc/resolv.conf` is a soft link to `/run/connman/resolv.conf`

With this configuration, my DNS does not work (example: cannot surf the web with Chrome/Firefox, dig google.com gives me no IP, and ping gives me "Name or service not known").
So, I manually change the nameserver `::1` with some valid IP (like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8). I need to do this every time that I turn on my computer.

I don't know if connman (Intel Connection Manager daemon) comes preinstalled in Ubuntu 17.10, or I have installed it when trying to install a VPN client. Searching on the web, it seems that I don't have a standard configuration. So, I tried stopping the service, but then I lose my connections and don't see the available networks in the (NetworkManager?) Applet.

I can see that connmand is listening on port 53 (but does not resolve well), and systemd-resolve is also listening on port 53 (but attached to 127.0.0.53):

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ":53 "
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21159/connmand      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      21159/connmand      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           21159/connmand      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1451/systemd-resolv 
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                21159/connmand
```

If I execute `systemd-resolve --status`, it gives me the correct DNS.

Relinking `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` also solves my problem.

So, how can I disable connman (at least as the DNS proxy) and reenable `systemd-resolve`? Is connman installed by default on Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it was as easy as:

1. removing connman:

   ```
   sudo apt remove connman
   ```
2. deleting resolv.conf:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. relinking to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

   ```
   sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resol.conf
   ```

The last 2 steps were necessary because without the `/etc/resolv.conf` managed by connman, NetworkManager managed it, putting "127.0.1.1" as DNS server (and there were no server listening there).

The man page of NetworkManager says that all it needs to let `systemd-resolve` manage `resolve.conf`, is to make a softlink to the `resolv.conf` file under any of the systemd directories.